# How to split a list item by separator and call a function on each of the seperated item?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

How to split a list item by comma and call a function `fun1` on each of separated item?

Here, I like to split `list1` by comma and pass each of it to `fun1` to build another list like `["11","13"]` in below example.

```
>>> def fun1(a):
...    return a+10
... 
>>> list1=["1,3"]
>>> [x for y in list1 for x in y.split(",")]
['1', '3']
>>> 
>>> [fun1(x) x for y in list1 for x in y.split(",")]
File "<stdin>", line 1
[fun1(x) x for y in list1 for x in y.split(",")]
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Comment: Is not `[fun1(x) for y in list1 for x in y.split(",")]` what you want? By the way you also need `int(a) + 10`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you do extra `x`?:

```
[fun1(x) x for y in list1 for x in y.split(",")]
```

Can be:

```
[str(fun1(int(x))) for y in list1 for x in y.split(",")]
```